# T-distribution parameters with QRM package

Tags: r, distributions, t-distribution, parameterization

I am fitting a t-distribution on some data I have using the `fit.st` function from the `QRM` package.

The function returns 2 set of parameters (`par.ses` and `par.ests`), both containing values for `nu`, `mu`, and `sigma`. The values for the 2 sets of parameters are quite different and I don't get which one to use.
I looked into the source code of the package function and from my understanding they solve the optimization problem through 2 different methods and return the 2 results regardless of the success of the first one. In that case I should take the `par.ests` results if `converged==TRUE` and the `par.ses` results if the convergence didn't happen.
Is my understanding correct?

Here is the code of the `fit.st` function in the package:

```
fit.st <- function(data, ...){
  if(is.timeSeries(data)) data <- series(data)
  mu <- mean(data)
  m2 <- mean((data - mu)^2)
  m4 <- mean((data - mu)^4)
  nu <- 4 + (6 * m2^2) / (m4 - 3 * m2^2)
  sigma <- sqrt((nu - 2) * m2 / nu)
  theta <- c(nu, mu, sigma)
  negloglik <- function(theta, y){
    - sum(log(dt((y - theta[2]) / abs(theta[3]), df = abs(theta[1]))) - log(abs(theta[3])))
  }
  optimfit <- optim(theta, fn = negloglik, y = data, ...)
  par.ests <- optimfit$par
  ifelse(optimfit$convergence == 0, converged <- TRUE, converged <- FALSE)
  par.ests[1] <- abs(par.ests[1])
  par.ests[2] <- abs(par.ests[2])
  nItheta <- hessian(negloglik, par.ests, y = data)
  asymp.cov <- solve(nItheta)
  loglh.max <- -negloglik(par.ests, y = data)
  par.ses <- sqrt(diag(asymp.cov))
  names(par.ests) <- c("nu", "mu", "sigma")
  names(par.ses) <- names(par.ests)
  dimnames(asymp.cov) <- list(names(par.ests), names(par.ests))
  list(converged = converged, par.ests = par.ests, par.ses = par.ses,
       asymp.cov = asymp.cov, ll.max = loglh.max)
}
```

and the link to the package documentation: https://rdrr.io/cran/QRM/src/R/Student.R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`par.ests` referes to the *parameter estimates*. `par.ses` refers to the *parameter standard errors*.

It is maybe not so obvious, since the function has no documentation. But you can see in these lines:

```
  nItheta <- hessian(negloglik, par.ests, y = data)
  asymp.cov <- solve(nItheta)
  loglh.max <- -negloglik(par.ests, y = data)
  par.ses <- sqrt(diag(asymp.cov))
```

that the function uses the hessian matrix to compute standard errors.

Comment: Cheers, i had read the code and thought they were using hessian to estimate model fit another way, didn't think of standard error. Thank you